# " [main] INFO expect4j.Expect4j - Dealing with EOF null " What exactly is this issue?

Tags: java, eof

I'm trying to execute the below piece of code.

As per my observation, i get " [main] INFO expect4j.Expect4j - Dealing with EOF null " when the output doesn't match to any of the matches defined in the code. But there is no chance of not being matched to any of the matches defined. As there is no proper documentation present for Expect4j, i'm not able to figure out what exactly is problem is. If someone has faced the same type of issue, Please help me out.

```
try {
  Process ps = rt.exec(commands);
  Expect4j expect4j = new Expect4j(ps);
  Match[] matches = {
    new TimeoutMatch(90000L, null),
    new RegExpMatch("Some String which matches console", null),
  };
  int outcome = expect4j.expect(matches);
  if(outcome == 1){
    //Do something here
  } else if (outcome == 0){
    //throw an error
  } 
  ps.destroy();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your process ends/complete before expecting any match.

Steps:

1. Process started
2. Expect4j object created with process
3. Process ends
4. Trying to match pattern with process output